# Char* array of chars, but int* not array of ints?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

In C99 a string is typically initialized by using the `char*` data type since there is no primitive "string" data type. This effectively creates an array of chars by storing the address of the first char in the variable:

```
FILE* out = fopen("out.txt", "w");
char* s = argv[1];
fwrite(s, 12, 1, out);
fclose(out);
//successfully prints out 12 characters from argv[1] as a consecutive string.
```

How does the compiler know that `char* s` is a string and not just the address of a singular `char`? If I use `int*` it will only allow one `int`, not an array of them. Why the difference?

My main focus is understanding how pointers, referencing and de-referencing work, but the whole `char*` keeps messing with my head.

Comment: The compiler does not know that `char* s` is a string. `char* s` is a pointer to char, as the same as `int* s` is a pointer to int. We can get the whole string as long as we reached a final '\0'.

Comment: "If I use int* it will only allow one int". That's not true. In C `int*` can be used as an array.

Comment: @AlanAu: No, pointers cannot be used as arrays.

Comment: The relationship between arrays and pointers can be confusing. Section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/) does a very good job of explaining it.

Comment: @KeithThompson Perhaps we are referring to different things. `int *i_array = malloc(10*sizeof int); i_array[1] = 1;`?

Comment: @AlanAu: `i_array` is a pointer, not an array. The prefix of the `[]` operator must be a pointer (which is often the result of the implicit conversion of an array). (Actually `[]` is commutative, but that's beside the point.)

Comment: declaring some variable `char *variable` does not automatically declares an array of characters, it only declares a pointer (a pointer and an array are different things)  You must care on this!!!  `string` type is not primitive even in C++.  You can construct it as a C++ `class` and let it behave like it does.

Answer (score 16):

> How does the compiler know that `char* s` is a string and not just the address of a singular char?

It doesn't. As far as "the compiler" is concerned, `char* s` is a pointer to char.

On the other hand, there are many library functions that assume that a `char*` points to an element of a [null-terminated sequence of `char`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string) (see for example [`strlen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen), [`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) etc.).

Note that `fwrite` does not make this assumption. It requires that you tell it how many bytes you want to write (and that this number doesn't take you beyond the bounds of the buffer pointed at by the first argument.)

> If I use `int*` it will only allow one int, not an array of them. Why the difference?

That is incorrect. The C language does not have a special case for `char*`. An `int*` can also point to an element of an array of `int`. In fact, you could write a library that uses `0` or another sentinel value to indicate the end of a sequence of `int`, and use it much in the same was as `char*` are used by convention.

Comment: I see a down-vote. If there is anything wrong with this answer, I'd like to know so I can consider fixing it.

Answer (score 7):

In your code

```
fwrite(s, 12, 1, out);
```

is equivalent to writing

> write 12 elements of size 1 byte, location starting from address `s` to the file pointed by `out`.

Here. a `char` is of one byte exactly, so you get the desired output.

> *How does the compiler know that `char* s` is a string and not just the address of a singular `char`?*

Well, it does not (and does not need to). You *asked* to (read from `s` and) write 12 bytes, so it will do that. If the memory is inaccessible, that's a *programming* mistake. `fwrite()` itself won't *handle* that.

**Beware**:

- If `s` is not allocated memory to be accessed upto `s[11]` (technically), it will be [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). It's upto the programmer to pass the *valid* values as argument.

In case of `int`, the size is `4` bytes (usually, on 32 bit system) and printing byte-by-byte won't give you the desired result.

In that case, you need to make use of `fprintf()` to print *formatted* output.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler won't have any idea other than char* is an address of a character. We can make it read the characters following by incrementing the address of the first character. The case is similar to any pointer int*,long* etc., compiler just treat a pointer as something points to an address of its type.