# how int *arr[] is array of pointers to int but char *arr[] is array of pointers to string?

Tags: arrays, c, string, pointers

In C

```
int *arr[]
```

is clearly an array of pointers to int but for

```
char *arr[]
```

is array of pointers to strings, how is that so. Then how does compiler differentiate in this two. I read this question-

[Char* array of chars, but int* not array of ints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31153422/char-array-of-chars-but-int-not-array-of-ints)

but with array of pointers to strings we are talking about big memory which compiler will have to create separately for strings and then to array of pointer do compiler treat variables separately somehow?

Comment: `char *arr[]` need not be arrays of pointers to strings because the contents may be `NULL` or pointers to data that are not null-terminated. It is an array of pointers to `char`.

Comment: @MikeCAT I don't get it what you mean by data that are not null-terminated.and yeah it should just create array of pointers to char and not to string

Comment: C has no type called `string`.  A string is an array of chars.  Like any array, a pointer to a string is a pointer to its first element.

Comment: Actually, `char **array[]` would be an array of pointers to strings.  `char *array[]` is an array of strings since, as others have pointed out, a string in C is just a `char*`.

Answer (score 2):

`int*` and `char*` behave the same, only the latter is treated as a C string while the former is not. A C string is just a pointer to `char`, as in "one or more characters depending on the size of the allocated memory at the destination".

```c
int *arr[] // Array of pointers to (at least one) int
char *arr[] // Array of pointers to (at least one) char (a.k.a. a "C string")
```

The compiler doesn't differentiate specifically, but all the default `str`-family functions only work with `char*`. By tradition and convention `char*` is how a C string is defined. It could very well have been `int*` under different circumstances, or even something else entirely such as how some operating systems use UTF-16 instead of 8-bit encoding.

In both cases `int* x[]` and `char* y[]` behave exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

No, the compiler does not differentiate them in general.

Consider the declarations

```
int a[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
int * pa[] = { a, a + 1,  a + 2 };
```

and

```
char s[] = { '1', '2', '3' };
char * ps[] = { s, s + 1, s + 2 };
```

As you can see there is no principal difference.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    int * pa[] = { a, a + 1,  a + 2 };
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof( pa ) / sizeof( *pa ); i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", *pa[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
    
    char s[] = { '1', '2', '3' };
    char * ps[] = { s, s + 1, s + 2 };

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof( ps ) / sizeof( *ps ); i++ )
    {
        printf( "%c ", *ps[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 2 3 
1 2 3
```

The only difference is that the Standard declares string functions that expect an argument of the type `char *` that points to the first element of a string while specially for the type `int *` such functions are absent.

Accordingly some output functions are specially designed to output strings when their arguments have the type `char *` because strings have the sentinel value `'\0'` unlike arrays with the element type `int`.

Answer (score 0):

"Arrays" in C are essentially wrappers for pointers - they do [have differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607128/in-c-are-arrays-pointers-or-used-as-pointers/4608421#4608421) but for the sakes of this question you can think of them as pointers to the first element within them.

Secondly, pointers *and* arrays in C can be subscripted - which is to say that you can use square brackets (`[]`) to perform array-like access to them. Underneath the hood this is just some pointer arithmetic to get the desired element.

This means that both `type* var` and `type var[]` can be an "array" of `type`, but `type* name` can also just be a plain old pointer to some data of type `type` - looking at it without context you can't really tell.

So `int *arr[]` is either an array of `int` "arrays" or of pointers to individual `int`s

And `char *arr[]` is either an array of `char` "arrays" or of pointers to individual `char`s

Finally - the C compiler doesn't care about what they are provided that you syntactically use them correctly - you could access an `int*` as an array which *isn't* one and get garbage data but it's not the job of the C compiler to tell you not to.